# Azure credit for expired MSDN subscription still active

Tags: azure, msdn, billing

Sometime ago i have MSDN Ultimate with MSDN subscription and use some beefits from Azure (~100$).
My subscription expires in January 2015, but now, every month i see this credit in my account. It is normal ? They do not charge me in the end of the year ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question to be asked at MS support.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say definite answer regarding your question as billing issues are too vary.

Why don't you issue support ticket on Microsoft support. **Billing is free to ask at any time**. [Go to support](https://manage.windowsazure.com/support) and submit in your language.

Answer (score 1):

Your MSDN subscription has nothing to do with Azure once you have activated your Azure benefit. Azure is a dedicated service which is activated through your MSDN subscription as a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago Azure notify me, that your credits is exhausted. Question closed.
4 month delay